# MySQL - Count occurences of records in different months

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table that contains all information I need but in a different format. I want to concatenate fields NAME and ACTIVITY to make it unique and group my dates by month and year. This query will always compare between 2 dates, do below when I specify MONTH1, actually means first month of analysis and MONTH2, second month of analysis. I also need to have the percentage of the difference between them.

```
Example of Raw table:
======================
Name    Activity      Date
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Paul    VideoGame     2015-02-01
John    Play Guitar   2015-03-05
Paul    Play Guitar   2015-02-01
Paul    Play Guitar   2015-02-15
Paul    VideoGame     2015-03-04
John    Play Guitar   2015-03-06

Output wanted:
==================
Name+Activity      Month1     Month2   Percentage
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
John+Play Guitar      0         2       +200%
Paul+VideoGame        1         1         0%
Paul+Play Guitar      2         0       -200%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the months, then you can do this with conditional aggregation.  I would put the `name` and `activity` in separate columns.  And, I'm not quite sure how the Percentage column is calculated:

```
select name, activity,
       sum(month(date) = 2) as month1,
       sum(month(date) = 3) as month2,
       sum(month(date) = 3) - sum(month(date) = 2)) as diff
from rawtable
group by name, activity;
```

You can concatenate `name` and `activity` as `concat_ws('+', name, activity) if you really want.  You can convert the`diff` to the format you want by multiplying by 100.